# How to iterate excel(.xlsm) sheet rows and columns using interop(c#.Net)

Tags: c#, excel

I have 5 columns(Name,department,Sales Details,Address in sheet(.xlsm) i have to fill this sheet using class object using for loop and fill the sheet after filling this sheet,same object data  some information need to fill sheet2 .I am new for excel sheet operations and interop as well, can some one let me know how to fill this data and programmatically how to switch to next sheet to fill the remaining data in sheet2.

```
for(int masterValues = 0; masterValues < frequencyValues.Count(); masterValues++)
{ MasterDataHeader name= new MasterDataHeader();
 masterDataHeader.department = Kvp[0].ToString();
 masterDataHeader.salesdetails= Kvp[1].ToString();
 masterDataHeader.adress = Kvp[2].ToString();
 masterDataHeader.Gebaude_art = Kvp[3].ToString();
 masterdtaheader.frequencyinfo=kvp[4]//need to update sheet2
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You must have Microsoft Office Excel 2007, or later versions, installed on your computer or on your server where this code will be executed.
- Add reference to Assemblies -> Extensions ->Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
- If you do not see the assemblies, see [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-install-office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2019).

---

> Here simple example how to add new workbook, add two new sheets, add data to those sheets, save the workbook and quit excel.

```
using MSExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static void FillExcel(IEnumerable<MasterDataHeader> data)
{
    MSExcel.Application excel = new MSExcel.Application { Visible = true };
    MSExcel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
    MSExcel.Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
    MSExcel.Worksheet sheet2 = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
    MasterDataHeader[] masterDataHeaders = data as MasterDataHeader[] ?? data.ToArray();

    int row = 0;
    foreach (var item in masterDataHeaders)
    {
        row++;
        sheet1.Cells[row, 1] = item.Name;
        sheet1.Cells[row, 2] = item.Department;
        sheet1.Cells[row, 3] = item.SalesDetails;
        sheet1.Cells[row, 4] = item.Adress;
    }

    row = 0;
    foreach (var item in masterDataHeaders)
    {
        row++;
        sheet2.Cells[row, 1] = item.GebaudeArt;
        sheet2.Cells[row, 2] = item.Frequencyinfo;
    }

    workbook.Save();
    excel.Quit();
}
```

---

> How to search for a employee number in `sheet1` and to find just the first occurrence

```
object missing = System.Type.Missing;
const int employeeNumber = 16845374;
MSExcel.Range employeeNumberFound = null;

employeeNumberFound = sheet1.UsedRange.Find(employeeNumber, missing,
    MSExcel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, MSExcel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
    MSExcel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MSExcel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
    missing, missing);

if (employeeNumberFound != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Employee number '{employeeNumber}' was found in cell '[{employeeNumberFound.Row},{employeeNumberFound.Column}]'");
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Employee number '{employeeNumber}' was not found");
}
```

For more information look e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges?view=vs-2019).

---

> Get last row in table2 and insert new row below it. Last row remains 32 in case when table2 is empty. And new row will not be incremented in case when table2 is empty.

```
var lastRowAsRange = sheet1.Cells[32, 2].CurrentRegion.Columns[1].Cells.Find("*", missing, missing, missing, 
    XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, missing, missing);

var lastRow = lastRowAsRange != null
    ? lastRowAsRange.Row
    : 32;

var newRow = lastRowAsRange != null
    ? lastRow + 1
    : lastRow;

bool inserted = sheet1.Rows[newRow].Insert(XlDirection.xlDown, XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove);

if (inserted)
{
    sheet1.Cells[newRow, 1] = "IT";
    sheet1.Cells[newRow, 2] = "100";
    sheet1.Cells[newRow, 3] = "hyd";
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have one more requirement I have  created three tables in one excell sheet ,second table i have filled data now i want add rows dynamically as data size increases. ts it there any to identify the cell index based on the content in the cell. For example in my table column name is employee number placed in []20,2] can i get this index dynamically using interop. Hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: Have a look at the second part of the edited answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for helping me in this regards.But I am looking how to create dynamically new row in second table assume that sheet have 3 tables, i want to insert one new row in second  table  this table have few  rows already  i mean  if table contains three rows with data i have find empty (4th) row in second table and need to insert data.Second table starts at (45,8) hope you are clear now  about my requirement

Comment: If you just want to get the index of next empry row, where you will insert data, the it will be best when you simply maintain a `last-row-pointer` in your c# code for each table and you simply increment this pointer with each new row inserted.

Comment: can you please post sample code how to maintain last-row-pointer as i am new for  these kind of  operations. My concern is table2 to start index(32,2)will come Name coulmn and so on  ..for this table only i need to find out last insert record when i am trying to get last row it is coming bottom of 3 table.Please help me it is quite urgent

Comment: When your table2 starts in cell 32,2 then you could try this: `var lastRow = sheet1.Cells[32, 2].CurrentRegion.Columns[1].Cells.Find("*", missing,
                missing, missing, MSExcel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MSExcel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, missing, missing).Row;`

Comment: Below code not inserting data please let me know what went wrong or is there any other ways to create row and insert data.Excel.Range line = (Excel.Range)ws.Rows[lastRow+1];
            line.Insert();
            line.Cells[lastRow + 1, 1] = "IT";
            line.Cells[lastRow + 1, 2] = "100";
            line.Cells[lastRow + 1, 3] = "hyd";

Comment: if there is no record present in table 2  last row value showing 1.if  one record present in table 2 the it is showing correct  value.Above code not at all inserting at specified position.Please  give me detailed code for inserting row and adding values to the newly created row.while inserting it should not disturb table3. please help me to complete my task.Thanks for you support throughout.

Comment: Thanks for your support,  above code inserting data but it is overlapping with table 3, next issue is data displayed in with out cell border.

Comment: Hi Daniel waiting for your reply.

Comment: Here I don't have any reply. This problem is beyond the question. I don't know your whole program or I don't know what your data looks like and why the data overlaps with table 3. You can post another question which is specific to your problems, so all the users of SO can answer it. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).